# Flutter widgets sharing despite having their own animation controller

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have a horizontal list of widgets that have the ability to be flipped on the X axis by the user when they drag on the widget. ( big coin in the middle)

[image]

Using the right and left arrows, the user can cycle through the coins they have.

However, if a user was to flip a coin, then click to cycle to another, the coin remains flipped, even though it is an entirely different object.

Coin:

```
class Coin extends StatefulWidget {
  final Image frontImage = const Image(image: AssetImage("assets/logo.png"));
  final Image back = const Image(image: AssetImage("assets/logoback.png"));

  const Coin({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CoinState createState() => _CoinState();
}

class _CoinState extends State<Coin>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;
  late Animation<double> animation;
  bool isFront = true;
  double dragPosition = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);

    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        dragPosition = animation.value;
        setImageSide();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Stack front = Stack(
      alignment: const Alignment(0, 0),
      children: [
        widget.frontImage,
        const Text("1", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100, color: Colors.white))
      ],
    );

    final angle = dragPosition / 180 * math.pi;
    final transform = Matrix4.identity()
      ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
      ..rotateY(angle);

    return GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) => setState(() {
        dragPosition -= details.delta.dx;
        dragPosition %= 360;
        setImageSide();
      }),
      onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
        double end = isFront ? (dragPosition > 180 ? 360 : 0) : 180;
        animation = Tween<double>(
          begin: dragPosition,
          end: end,
        ).animate(controller);
        controller.forward(from: 0);
      },
      child: Transform(
          transform: transform,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: isFront
              ? front
              : Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.identity()..rotateY(math.pi),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: widget.back)),
    );
  }

  void setImageSide() {
    if (dragPosition <= 90 || dragPosition >= 270) {
      isFront = true;
    } else {
      isFront = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Home page:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  int _currentIndex = 1;
  final List _coins = const [widgets.Coin(), widgets.Coin(), widgets.Coin()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // Main homepage contents
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
              // Column Alignment
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,

              // Main body of home page
              children: [
                Text(_currentIndex.toString()),

                const Spacer(), // Spacing

                // Centered Flip Coin widget
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, bottom: 40),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [

                      // Back coin button
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.grey[600]),
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_currentIndex != 0) {
                            setState(() {
                              _currentIndex--;
                            });
                          }}),

                      _coins[_currentIndex],   // Coin widget

                      // Forward coin button
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, color: Colors.grey[600]),
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_currentIndex < (_coins.length - 1)) {
                            setState(() {
                              _currentIndex++;
                            });
                          }})
                    ])),

                const Spacer(), // Spacing

                // Pushup button widget
                const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
                    child: widgets.PushupButton()),

                // Group information widget
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: widgets.GroupInfo(),
                ),
              ])),
        );
  }
}
```

Github (may be slightly old, mostly different names for files)
https://github.com/bens-schreiber/pushupapp

I have tested to make sure that the right and left button is actually cycling through the objects by making it print the current index and object, so I can confirm it is cycling through.

Let me know if anyone sees why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how they were sharing the `isFront` variable, but when I moved `isFront` from the `CoinState` class to the `Coin` class it then properly saved the orientation of the coin.